# How to use pod package to create a compiled framework

Tags: frameworks, cocoapods, podspec

I am trying to use the cocoa pods package extension to create a compiled framework.

The example project with source code and pod spec  can be found here:

https://github.com/avnerbarr/TestFramework.git

The resulting output can be found here:

https://github.com/avnerbarr/TestFrameworkCompiled

The main idea is that I want to create a project using cocoa pods.

When I will need to distribute the close source - I need all of the dependencies to be contained in the resulting framework.

I don't want my end users to be forced to use cocoa pods.

But it would be great if I could leverage the cocoa pods abilities to compile and package everything together.

How should I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`vendored_frameworks`](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#vendored_frameworks) attribute for this. It allows you to specify a path to a compiled framework that will be linked with the users application.

```
spec.ios.vendored_frameworks = 'Frameworks/MyFramework.framework'
```

Comment: The problem is that the compilation isn't correct. The dependencies aren't added correctly to the compiled framework that the pod package command should have created . For instance I added AFNetworking as a dependency in the pod spec. When integrating the outputted framework to a separate project I couldn't compile that project because of the fact that AFNetworking wasn't included

Comment: The question was about how to *create* a compiled framework. Does `vendored_frameworks` actually do this? (If so, it doesn't work for me!)