# Hiding implementation in cocoa touch framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am creating a Cocoa Touch framework in objective C, how can I hide the implementaion (.m) files when it is distributed via Cocoapods. I know that hiding implementation is easy in static library but How can I do the same in frameworks? Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A framework is a collection of resources; it collects a static library and its header files into a single structure that Xcode can easily incorporate into your projects.

So framework actually hides your implementation, as it just contains library with headers and resources.

You should distribute a builded framework via cocoapods.

Check this: [How to use pod package to create a compiled framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30914987/how-to-use-pod-package-to-create-a-compiled-framework)

Comment: Hi, I have [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52230093/hide-implementations-in-framework-file) could please help me? Thanks.